# Highlight a cell (i.e. change it's back color) in a GridView based on its value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a GridView on a web page.  Most of the fields being displayed are "Y/N" fields.  I've been asked to change the background color of all cells where the value is "N".  I can't seem to find any sample code where something like this is done, can anyone help me out?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
foreach (GridView row in DataGrid_AAReview.Rows)
{
   if (row.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text == "N")
   {
       row.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
   }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be done over some presentation layer?

Comment: @h__ Yea, it should, but some people are going to use code behind as mush as they can, i've been like that too

Answer (score 0):

Using `row.Rows[0].Cells[0]` makes no sense. You should refer to the `cell` under the `row`, not to `row.Rows`.

Also - You wrote `foreach (GridView row in DataGrid_AAReview.Rows)` which also makes no sense - iterating rows should be `foreach (GridViewRow row in...`

Try this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in DataGrid_AAReview.Rows)
{
   if (row.Cells[0].Text.ToUpper() == "N")
   {
       row.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
   }
}
```

As you requested (in comments section), iterating through all columns:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in DataGrid_AAReview.Rows)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < DataGrid_AAReview.Columns.Count, i++)
   {
        if (row.Cells[i].Text.ToUpper() == "N")
        {
             row.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: 'GridView' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow row in DataGrid_AAReview.Rows)

Comment: See my answer please

Comment: OK, that removed the error, but I think it needs to account for every column in the gridview.  Right now it's just looking at cell 0.  I'm still a n00b at c#, how would I also iterate through all columns?

Comment: I gotta work on this a bit.  It's the weirdest thing; I get a proper response for DataGrid_AAReview.Rows.Count and DataGrid_AAReview.Columns.Count, but for some reason it thinks every cell in my GridView is empty so I never see the background color change.  But when the page is done running it shows me a full grid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137945/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-johnny-bones).